# Adding Branches to a Recursive Tree

Tags: mit-scratch

I am struggling to build new branches on my recursive tree, and I would like to make this tree with a variable.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide a code so we can reproduce the problem? maybe the .sb file or xml file for this code

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to add a `repeat until _` loop? That would probably help...